# Excel 2016 won't show Npgsql Data Provider

Tags: npgsql

although I can update NPGSQL queries in excel files created on my old computer with Excel 2013 , I cannot create a new excel file and connect to a PGSQL datasource, as there is not NPGSQL datasource in the Excel 2016 ribbon `Data > New Query > From Database` - as shown in [this post](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Connect-to-a-PostgreSQL-database-Power-Query-bf941e52-066f-4911-a41f-2493c39e69e4).

I have checked the GAC (at `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL`) and the `npgsql.dll` is located there. I've tried NPGSQL version 2.2.7, 3.1.3, and 3.1.4.

I have also checked the machine.configs (`C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Config\machine.config` and `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Config\machine.config`) and both contain the reference to the DLL:

```
<system.data>
 <DbProviderFactories>
  <add name="Microsoft SQL Server Compact Data Provider 4.0" invariant="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0" description=".NET Framework Data Provider for Microsoft SQL Server Compact" type="System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeProviderFactory, System.Data.SqlServerCe, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91" />
  <add name="Npgsql Data Provider" invariant="Npgsql" description=".Net Data Provider for PostgreSQL" type="Npgsql.NpgsqlFactory, Npgsql, Version=2.2.7.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=5d8b90d52f46fda7" support="FF" />
 </DbProviderFactories>
</system.data>
```

I am using Office365 Excel V.16 32bit.

Comment: Try a different version of Npgsql. Worked for me. Hint: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44795817/2714017