# Cannot install Microsoft Power Bi Postgre SQL connector

Tags: c#, .net, postgresql, powerbi, powerbi-datasource

I am trying to use Microsoft Power Bi to connect to a PostgreSQL database.

When I go to **Get Data** it just says that **the connector requires one or more additional components to be installed before it can be used**

1. I have installed Microsoft Power Bi version: 2.47.4766.801 64-bit (June 2017).
2. I have installed Npgsql 3.2.3.
3. I have installed VS Studio 2017 Community and added the dll files to the assembly using the VS Studio command prompt.
4. I have edited my machine.config file.

below

```
<system.data>
  <DbProviderFactories>
    <add name="Npgsql Data Provider" invariant="Npgsql" description=".Net Framework Data Provider for PostgreSQL Server" type="Npgsql.NpgsqlFactory, Npgsql, Version=3.2.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=5d8b90d52f46fda7"/>
  </DbProviderFactories>
</system.data>
```

5. I am running Windows 10 so I already have .NET framework 4.5 installed.
    6. I restart my PC, open up Power Bi and try to connect to Postgre again and I get the same message that **the connector requires one or more additional components to be installed before it can be used.**

The tracer log from my Power Bi can be found here:

https://www.sendspace.com/file/vleze0

How can I get this thing to work?  It's driving me crazy!
 
Thanks

Answer (score 20, accepted):

There seems to be some problem with the latest Npgsql versions.
Succeded to connect with [Npgsql 3.1.8](https://github.com/npgsql/npgsql/releases/download/v3.1.8/Npgsql-3.1.8.msi)  version.
First uninstall the existing version then install and restart.

Comment: This is madness even in 2018. Even though there's already npgsql 4.0.2 this still won't work and I had to get 3.1.8 ...

Comment: Thank you - this is still the only way I could connect using npgsql to excel 2016 64bt   (except using ODBC)

Comment: January 2019 is here and still this is the only solution that works

Comment: Still true in April 2019. :-(

Comment: And in August 2020

Comment: And in Jan 2021.

Comment: And in Mar 2021 - thanks so much for this!